# Static parameterized methods in Java

Tags: java, generics

I thought I understood generics. However, in this example, I cannot figure out why line  `isIn1(new Class2(1), arr);` is compiled and line  `isIn2(new Class2(1), arr);` is not compiled.

```
class E1{};
class E2{};

class Class1 implements Comparable<Class1> {
    int i;

    public Class1(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Class1 class1 = (Class1) o;
        return i == class1.i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Class1 o) {
        return this.i - o.i;
    }
}

class Class2 implements Comparable<Class2> {
    int i;

    public Class2(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Class2 class2 = (Class2) o;
        return i == class2.i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Class2 o) {
        return this.i - o.i;
    }
}


public class G05Demo2 {

    public static <T, V extends T> void isIn1(T x, V[] y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (x.equals(y[i])) {
                System.out.println(" Yes, is in ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Not is in ");
            }
        }
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> void isIn2(T x, V[] y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (x.equals(y[i])) {
                System.out.println(" Yes, is in ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Not is in ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Class1[] arr = {new Class1(1)};

        isIn1(new Class1(1), arr); //  Yes, is in
        isIn1(new Class2(1), arr); //  Not is in    - why?

        isIn2(new Class1(1), arr); //  Yes, is in
        isIn2(new Class2(1), arr); //  NOT compiled - why?

        G05Demo2.<Class1, Class1>isIn1(new Class1(1), arr); //  Yes, is in
        G05Demo2.<Class2, Class1>isIn1(new Class2(1), arr); //  NOT compiled (type checking works, since they are explicitly specified)

        G05Demo2.<Class1, Class1>isIn2(new Class1(1), arr); //  Yes, is in
        G05Demo2.<Class2, Class1>isIn2(new Class2(1), arr); //  NOT compiled (type checking works, since they are explicitly specified)

        E1[] arr2 = {new E1()};
        isIn1(new E2(), arr2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Class1 and Class2 are unrelated, so when V is Class1 and T is Class2, V extends T isn't satisfied.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the staticness. Toys get exactly the same with generic instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
isIn1(new Class2(1), arr);
```

prints "Not is in" because `Class2.equals` returns `false` when `this` and `o` are not instances of the *exact* same class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    //          here VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Class2 class2 = (Class2) o;
    return i == class2.i;
}
```

`arr` contains an instance of `Class1`, but you passed an instance of `Class2` as the first parameter to `isIn1`.

---

```
isIn2(new Class2(1), arr);
```

Does not compile because there is no types that satisfy the constraints you specified in `isIn2` that can be inferred. Specifically, there has to be a type `T` that is a subtype of `Comparable<T>` and a type `V` that is a subtype of `T`. `Class2` would also have to be compatible with `T`, and `Class1[]` would have to be compatible with `V[]`.

---

"How about `T` is `Class2` and `V` is `Class1`?" you might say:

```
Main.<Class2, Class1>isIn2(new Class2(1), arr);
```

That doesn't work because `Class1` is not a subtype of `Class2`. They are unrelated at all! The similar `isIn1` call fails for the same reason.

---

Why does

```
isIn1(new Class2(1), arr);
```

compile then?

By not specifying the generic type parameters, the compiler can try its best to infer the types so that the code compiles. Also note that `isIn1` has one fewer constraint than `isIn2`.

Here, one solution is `T` is `Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>`, and `V` is `Class1`.

```
Main.<Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>, Class1>isIn1(new Class2(1), arr);
```

You can check that they satisfy the constraints by using the sub typing rules described in [Section 4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) of the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

For `isIn1`, both `T` and `V` can be inferred as `Object`. (Because of this, there is no point in these type variables, you may as well use `Object` explicitly).

For `isIn2`, `T` is inferred as `Class1`; since `Class2` doesn't extend that, the compiler rejects the code.